# How to prove □(∀x□φ → □φ) → (◇∀x□φ → ◇□φ) in s5?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

By S5, I mean the system consisting of the following axioms:

K: □(φ→ψ) → (□φ→□ψ)

T: □φ → φ

5: ◇φ → □◇φ

I believe the result I want to prove follows from K alone, but I cannot figure out how. If anyone can offer an explanation I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I would not assume that you can just derive this statement from one axiom.  Indeed, it appears that I have to use 5 and T and the deduction theorem and probably a few other things just to start...

Comment: This is crossposted to Philosophy Stackexchange. It's considered bad practice to simultaneously post the same question to more than one site on the network.

Comment: I agree with the commenter on Philosophy Stackexchange that the sentence you want to prove is puzzling. Is $x$ free in $\phi$? Isn't $\forall x \square \phi \rightarrow \square \phi$ a tautology? What is the motivation for proving  this sentence?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Apologies for the poor post and crossposting. It is step (3) from the proof of the Barcan Formula in S5 done here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/actualism/proofBF.html

Comment: The context helps a lot! Now I can clearly see what's going on. Always good to include in the question your motivation for asking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [link](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/actualism/proofBF.html) you posted in the comments, it is claimed that $$\square (\forall x \square \varphi \rightarrow \square \varphi)\rightarrow (\lozenge \forall x \square \varphi \rightarrow \lozenge \square \varphi)$$ is a theorem of S5 modal propositional logic. Well, that's not exactly right, because this is not a propositional sentence (as indicated by the presence of the quantifier $\forall x$). What is meant is that this sentence is a *substitution instance* of the propositional theorem $$(\star)\quad\square (P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow (\lozenge P \rightarrow \lozenge Q)$$
with $\forall x\square \varphi$ substituted for $P$ and $\square \varphi$ substituted for $Q$ in $(\star)$.

Now it should be intuitively clear that $(\star)$ is already a theorem of the modal logic K, since it is valid on every Kripke frame. Suppose we're at a world $w$ at which $\square (P\rightarrow Q)$ is true. If $\lozenge P$ is true, then $P$ holds at a world $w'$ accessible from $w$. But then $(P\rightarrow Q)$ holds at $w'$, so $Q$ holds at $w'$, so $\lozenge Q$ holds at $w$.

Ok, that was a semantic proof of $(\star)$ on Kripke frames. How would you give a formal proof? I'll give a sketch. Rewriting $\lozenge$ as $\lnot \square \lnot$, we want to prove
$$(\star')\quad\square (P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow (\lnot \square \lnot P \rightarrow \lnot \square \lnot Q).$$
By propositional logic, $(P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow (\lnot Q\rightarrow \lnot P)$, so by necessitation and K,   $\square(P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow \square(\lnot Q\rightarrow \lnot P)$. Now if we assume $\square(P\rightarrow Q)$, by Modus Ponens we get $\square(\lnot Q\rightarrow \lnot P)$, so by K again, $\square \lnot Q \rightarrow \square \lnot P$. Taking the contrapositive again gives $\lnot \square \lnot P \rightarrow \lnot \square \lnot Q$, as desired.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much!